# "compared with" vs "in comparison with" vs "assessed in comparison with"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

what would you consider more appropriate?

-"She is writing her thesis under my guidance on a topic related to the Australian tax system compared with the European one", 
-"She is writing her thesis under my guidance on a topic related to the Australian tax system in comparison with the European one"
-"She is writing her thesis under my guidance on a topic related to the Australian tax system assessed in comparison with the European one"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second one, but I would rephrase it as:

```
I am guiding the writing of her thesis that compares the Australian tax system with the European system.
```

Presumably all theses have a topic, so I feel that it is unnecessary to belabor the point by stating so.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> *I am guiding her as she writes her thesis that compares the Australian tax system with the European one*.